# Is it possible to overload a method in webservices?

Tags: web-services

Is it possible to overload a method in web service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you have to use [**MessageName**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute.messagename.aspx) property of web method.

Take a look at this article.

[**Overloading Web Services**](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/OverloadingInWebService.aspx)