# Method overloading in webservices

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have 2 question related to the web services.

1. How we achieve the method overloading in web services.
2. How to implement security(authentication) in web services.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to overload a method in webservices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043500/is-it-possible-to-overload-a-method-in-webservices)

Comment: Please do not combine questions. Your first question is an exact duplicate (and shows up in the search results when you type this question title...), and the second is not related to the first.

Comment: You should not use ASP.NET Web Services at all (ASMX). All new web service development should use WCF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay for overloading:

```
[WebMethod(MessageName = "MaxInt", Description = "Compare two int values 
and return the max value", EnableSession = true)]
public int MaxValue(int a, int b)
{
   return (a > b ? a : b);
}
[WebMethod(MessageName = "MaxFloat", Description = "Compare two float values 
and return the max value", EnableSession = true)]
public float MaxValue(float a, float b)
{
   return (a > b ? a : b);
}
```

What do you mean precisely by authentication? You can obviously use a validation key to access webservice. The question is confusing. Elaborate please.

Answer (score 6):

> How we achieve the method overloading in web services.

If you are using SOAP you can't. Method names must have unique names in the exported WSDL. Depending on the technology you are using there are different ways to specify a method name. For example in WCF you could use the [`[OperationContract]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.aspx) attribute to specify a name:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract(Name = "Foo")]
    void Foo();

    [OperationContract(Name = "FooWithId")]
    void Foo(int id);
}
```

> How to implement security(authentication) in web services.

The [following guide](http://wcfsecurityguide.codeplex.com/) is a very good start for implementing security in WCF.

Comment: when I am not using SOAP in that case how can I achive method overloading?

Comment: @Vijjendra, what are you using then?

Comment: I have seen that on following link.. that we can implement overloading in webservices. but you says no.. that's why I am asking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043500/is-it-possible-to-overload-a-method-in-webservices

Comment: @Vijjendra, no you can't expose them to the client in the WSDL. In WCF you have the possibility to provide a different method name as shown in my example. This method name will be used to expose the method to the client. But it has to be unique. You obviously aren't using WCF but classic ASMX webservices which are deprecated now. You should definitely consider migrating your code to WCF.