# Add web service with 2 interfaces

Tags: c#, web-services, interface

I am updating a web service from VB to C#.  This is a WCF service.
The web service implements 2 interfaces.
When I add the web service to a test application, only one of the interfaces is accessible.
When I try to invoke a method from the second interface, the method signature is not recognized.

This works in VB and I am hoping I can do the same in C#.
This is the implementation of the web service class:

PayService Interface:

```
namespace PayService
{
    [ServiceContract (Namespace...)]
    public interface IPayService
    {
        //Initiate a credit card authorization.
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void Authorize(...12 arguments here...);
}
```

PayService2 Interface:

```
namespace PayService2
    {
        [ServiceContract (Namespace...)]
        public interface IPayService
        {
            //Initiate a credit card authorization.
            [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
            void Authorize(...13 arguments here...);
    }


public partial class PayService : IPayService, IPayService2
{
  Authorize(...there are 12 arguments here)
  Authorize(...there are 13 arguments here)
  ...more methods but they are not a problem.
}
```

The calling application is just a web application to test the web service.

```
//Create instance of PayService
PayService.PayServiceClient payService = new PayService.PayServiceClient();
payService.Authorize(...12 arguments)  //this one works fine

payService.Authorize(...13 arguments)  //this one is not recognized
```

Does anyone have an idea why not all of the methods would be visible in the web application that uses the PayService?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a WCF service?

Comment: No, without telling us how you implemented *calling* this webservice, none of us will be able to help you. We're not psychic, sorry :)

Comment: Sorry...I added more details.  Is this enough info?

Comment: Does the OperationContract idea help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5689054/404

Comment: I added the 'Name=' attribute to the OperationContract and still, the web application only recognizes one of the Authorize methods.  Secondly, I read that the operations are defined by the method signature, not method names only.  Can I have 2 methods with the same name but with different signatures?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/720389/487940

You basically want to combine the 2 interfaces into a single interface, like this:

```
public interface IMyInterface : IInterface1, IInterface2
```

Comment: That link was very good.  A second answer has a link that explains how you can have multiple endpoints for the same service using 2 interfaces.  If I can get that to work, that is what I need.  Here is the comment and link:                                    Multiple Endpoints at a Single ListenUri: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395210.aspx

Comment: This will not work for me because I have a method with the same name in both interfaces but different method signatures...see above the parameter lists.  It looks like I will have to use the multiple endpoint implementation.