# Error while overloading methods in webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, web-config, asmx

I have seen and pass through [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043500/is-it-possible-to-overload-a-method-in-webservices) but end up with an error as

[image]

In the service I have web methods as

```
[WebMethod(MessageName = "AddWithMoreParam",Description="More parameters", EnableSession=true)]
public bool UpdateMovies(string userName, string role, string movieName, string releaseDate)
{        
    BlogController con = new BlogController();
    BlogInfo info=new BlogInfo();
    info.MovieName=movieName;
    info.ReleaseDate=releaseDate;
    return con.UpdateMovies(info);        
}


[WebMethod(MessageName = "AddWithLessParam", Description = "Less parameters", EnableSession = true)]
public bool UpdateMovies(string movieName, string releaseDate)
{
    BlogController con = new BlogController();
    BlogInfo info = new BlogInfo();
    info.MovieName = movieName;
    info.ReleaseDate = releaseDate;
    return con.UpdateMovies(info);
}
```

May be the problem is related to webservicebinding but I am confused with it and cannot go forward.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: In the browser it suggests the error as in the image above.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Remove `[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]` from Web Service

Comment: This worked as the use of method overloading. But I am not still confirmed as it conforms to WS-I basic profile v1.1.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really overload web service operations. The languages used to describe SOAP web services (WSDL and XSD) have no concept of overloads.

There is a hack you can sometimes use, by setting the `MessageName` property of the `WebMethod` attribute. However, this breaks WS-I BP1 compliance, as your error message clearly states. WS-I BP1 prohibits the use of this sort of "overloading" because not all web service stacks support it.

The solution is to give up and use a different name for each method.

FYI, SOAP also has no concept of other programming language constructs, like default parameters, indexers, generics, enums, etc. It is not object oriented, so don't get stuck on using object-oriented concepts or concepts from your favorite programming language. These can, of course, be used in the implementation of your service, but not in the definition of it.

Comment: Sir, I with my co-workers will find a better way with WCF services in the coming days. But this time I have to work with Webservices.Is there any alternatives to do so?

Comment: I now have better understanding of .asmx.

Comment: The simplest alternative is to just not do overloads. Also, FYI, WCF was first released seven years ago. You're not just a little behind the times. You're far behind the times, and you're using code that will never be fixed if bugs are discovered. That's not impressive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a method with new name. You can write and compile the overloaded method in webservices, but when the WSDL will be generated it won't work. There is an alternative to achieve this which is described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30018/Function-Overloading-in-Web-Services?msg=2896156#xx2896156xx)

Comment: My apologies, but I have already been to this site but it does not help me any more.